# rails polymorphic query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Why is it that

```
@discussions = Discussion.where(:discussable => @discussable)
```

doesn't work. yet this work:

```
@discussions = Discussion.where(:discussable_id => @discussable.id, :discussable_type => @discussable.class.to_s)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first one you are passing a complete model instance. The attribute must be an id(integer) and you pass an object. The second one is ok, because you pass the id(correctly).

Comment: i thought rails is smarter than that. I guess where method is stricter than find. Thanks!

Comment: there is actually a reason. Passing an object can be done through serialization. That is why an integer has to be an integer :)

Comment: That's pretty awkward and sluggish when you have to specify both _id and _type each time you query polymorphic association. I though Rails can be smarter and detect such cases.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like pull request which fixes this issue was merged into master 1 month ago:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7273

Unfortunately, it will be only released in Rails 4 :(